# Griaule biometrics DLL control did not work in 64 bit O.S

Tags: dll, 64-bit, biometrics

We purchase a licensed Control for **Biometric** from **Griaule biometrics**.
we are using this Control on a **Window Application's form**.The `AxInterop.GrFingerXLib Dll`  control is working fine on the **32 bit** operating System.

But due to some reason we change the Operating system from **32 bi**t to **64 bit**.
On the **64 bit** operating system the window form on which we are using the `AxInterop.GrFingerXLib DLL` Control is unable to Create.

And if we remove the Control from the Form working fine.

We use the  the latest release of **Fingerprint SDK 2009** but it still not working.

We also did that we remove the Control from the form and then again include the control on the form then it gives some `ActiveX control not find` related Error.

We are using **Visual Studio 2008** and **Windows Server 2008 64 bit** operating System.

Its urgent issue and we want to resolve it as soon as possible.

Please provide a needful support.

Answer (score 3):

I Have Found The Solution 
When I build the .EXE with x86 Configuration the Problem have been resolved

Steps i Followed
Build-->Configuration Manages

Here set the application's target platform. to x86

Build the Project

u will find a Newly created Folder x86 under Bin Directory

use this Exe in 64 bit Machine it will work fine!